# App Rejected: Crashes on iPad

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, crash

I had tested my app on iPhone models, not iPads - I assumed that if it ran on an iPhone it would run on an iPad in "compatibility mode"... Oh well. So it got rejected. I ran it on the iPad simulator as soon as I got that rejection (I was pissed), and sure enough, it crashes... But it doesn't give me any info as to why. The log window simply shows `(lldb)` and it crashes here:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Looking at other answers directed me to change "Supported Devices" in the `plist` but my `plist` doesn't have that included.

In my launch images and icons assets file, I don't include iPad images - could that be the problem? Others have also recommended removing the main.storyboard file.

Comment: You should be able to get a crash log. Even if just off the device.

Answer (score 0):

In your Xcode project, go to the breakpoints navigator (cmd-7), at the bottom of the screen hit the + and "Add Exception Breakpoint".

Now when you build and run, Xcode should break at the line that's actually causing the crash instead of just in the `main()`.

Note: You can right click on the "All Exceptions" breakpoint and hit "Move breakpoint to...User" so that breakpoint will always be there for all your projects.